# R Shiny use Sortable List (with Sortable.js) in dynamic renderUI enviroment

Tags: javascript, r, drag-and-drop, shiny

Based on the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950134/shiny-widget-to-change-the-order-of-elements-in-a-vector) I tried to implement this kind of sortable list in a dynamic renderUI enviroment:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(stringi)

sortableList <- function(inputId, value) {
  tagList(
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"))),
    singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src = "sortableList.js"))),
    tags$div(id = inputId,class = "sortableList list-group",
             tagList(
               sapply(value,function(x){
                 tags$div(class="list-group-item","data-id"=x,x)
               },simplify = F)))
  )
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(".list-group {cursor: -webkit-grab}")),
    tags$head(tags$style(".list-group-item.sortable-chosen {cursor: -webkit-grabbing}")),

    actionButton('actbtn', 'add ui'),

    uiOutput("moreControls"),

    textOutput('test'),
    textOutput('test1'),
    textOutput('test2'),
    textOutput('test3')
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderPrint({str(input$sortable_list0)})
  output$test1 <- renderPrint({str(input$sortable_list1)})
  output$test2 <- renderPrint({str(input$sortable_list2)})
  output$test3 <- renderPrint({str(input$sortable_list3)})

  output$moreControls <- renderUI({

    print(input$actbtn)
    times <- input$actbtn
    test <- tagList(lapply(0:input$actbtn, function(numb){
      fluidRow(
        column(6,
               box(
                 div(class="list-inline",
                     div(class = 'my-list',
                         tags$div(class="list-group-item", "1"),
                         tags$div(class="list-group-item", "2"),
                         tags$div(class="list-group-item", "3"),
                         tags$div(class="list-group-item", "4"),
                         tags$div(class="list-group-item", "5"),
                         tags$div(class="list-group-item", "6")
                     ),
                     sortableList(paste0("sortable_list", numb),
                                  c(paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                    paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                    paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                    paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                    paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                    paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " ")))
                 )
                 ,width = 12, height = '300px')
        ))
    })
    )
    return(div(id=letters[(times %% length(letters)) + 1], test))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

But as soon as it re-renders the shiny-input-bound gets lost and I get the following JavaScript error in the sortableList.js in line 8:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of null
```

I also tried it via `insertUI()`, but it results in similar issues. Just the first inserted UI works flawlessly.

```
  observeEvent(input$actbtn,{
    insertUI(
      selector = "#actbtn",
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = tags$div(id = paste0('divID_', input$actbtn), box(
        column( 6,
                tags$head(tags$style(".list-group {cursor: -webkit-grab}")),
                tags$head(tags$style(".list-group-item.sortable-chosen {cursor: -webkit-grabbing}")),
                div(class="list-inline", style = 'overflow-y: scroll; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #d2d6de;; border-radius: 5px;',
                    sortableList(paste0('sortable_list', input$actbtn),
                                 c(paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                   paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                   paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                   paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                   paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " "),
                                   paste(unlist(strsplit(stri_rand_lipsum(1, start_lipsum = F), " "))[1:10], collapse = " ")))
                )

        )
      )
      )
    )
  })
```

**Edit update:**

You need to save the **sortableList.js**  from the mentioned answered question above in your `www` folder of the app.

**sortableList.js**

```
var sortableListBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();
$.extend(sortableListBinding, {
  find: function(scope) {
    return $(scope).find(".sortableList");
  },
  getValue: function(el) {
    if (typeof Sortable.active != 'undefined'){
      return Sortable.active.toArray();
    }
    else return "";
  },
  subscribe: function(el, callback) {
    $(el).on("change.sortableListBinding", function(e) {
      callback();
    });
  },
  unsubscribe: function(el) {
    $(el).off(".sortableListBinding");
  },
  initialize: function(el) {
    Sortable.create(el,{
      onUpdate: function (evt) {
          $(el).trigger("change");
    }});
  }
});

Shiny.inputBindings.register(sortableListBinding);
```

**Edit UPDATE 2:**

I found a solution to get the functionality of sortable list in R Shiny, which works pretty fine for my case: 
`orderInput()` from the dev version of the `shinyjqui` package.

Comment: All I get when I run your code is when I press add I get a null and [1] 0
attr(,"class")
[1] "integer"                "shinyActionButtonValue" on the R console

Comment: I added the sortableList.js file from the mentioned question, which is as well needed for this case. The output you mentioned is to control how often the the button has been pressed.